# Loop through different controls on a user form and read/write the value VBA

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I would like to somehow get the value from the different controls on the user form and then write them on the sheet after that if the user form is closed down and re opened if a name is selected in the combobox then load all data in the form back ready to change values. I have 13 rows that a user can use on the user form.

[image: Order id]

[image: user form]

[image: Sheet data]

In my code the writing the data to the sheet will write all item selected i want but it takes too long because all of the loops and ifs. Is there a better way to achieve what i want?

```
    Private Sub FillingInForm()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim WS As Worksheet

    Dim ctl As MSForms.Control
    Dim lbl As MSForms.Label
    Dim cmb As MSForms.ComboBox
    Dim txtbox As MSForms.TextBox
    Dim optbtn As MSForms.OptionButton

    Set WS = ActiveSheet

With WS

    For i = 1 To ItemsListFrame.Controls.Count
        For Each ctl In ItemsListFrame.Controls
            If TypeName(ctl) = "Label" Then
                If ctl.Tag = "GroupItem" & i Then
                    Set lbl = ctl
                    If Controls("Item" & i).Value <> vbNullString Then
                        .Range("A" & i + 6).Offset(0, 0).Value = Me.OrderNo.Value
                        .Range("A" & i + 6).Offset(0, 1).Value = Me.NextCollectionDate.Text
                        .Range("A" & i + 6).Offset(0, 1).Value = Format(.Range("A" & i + 6).Offset(0, 1).Value, "dd/mm/yyyy")
                        .Range("A" & i + 6).Offset(0, 8).Value = Me.DateReturnBy.Value
                        .Range("A" & i + 6).Offset(0, 8).Value = Format(.Range("A" & i + 6).Offset(0, 8).Value, "dd/mm/yyyy")
                        Controls("OrderLbl" & i).Enabled = True
                    End If
                End If

            ElseIf TypeName(ctl) = "ComboBox" Then
                If ctl.Tag = "GroupItem" & i Then
                    Set cmb = ctl
                    If Controls("Item" & i).Value <> vbNullString Then
                        Controls("Item" & i).Enabled = True
                    End If
                    If Controls("Item" & i).Value <> vbNullString Then
                        .Range("A" & i + 6).Offset(0, 2).Value = Controls("Item" & i).Text
                    End If
                End If

            ElseIf TypeName(ctl) = "TextBox" Then
                If ctl.Tag = "GroupItem" & i Then
                    Set txtbox = ctl
                    If Controls("Item" & i).Value <> vbNullString Then
                        .Range("A" & i + 6).Offset(0, 3).Value = Controls("Qty" & i).Value
                        .Range("A" & i + 6).Offset(0, 4).Value = Controls("UnitPrice" & i).Value
                        .Range("A" & i + 6).Offset(0, 5).Value = Controls("SubTotal" & i).Value
                        .Range("A" & i + 6).Offset(0, 7).Value = Controls("Comments" & i).Value
                        Controls("Qty" & i).Enabled = True
                        Controls("UnitPrice" & i).Enabled = True
                        Controls("SubTotal" & i).Enabled = True
                        Controls("Comments" & i).Enabled = True
                    End If
                End If
            ElseIf TypeName(ctl) = "OptionButton" Then
                If ctl.Tag = "GroupItem" & i Or ctl.Tag = "InOut" & i Then
                    Set optbtn = ctl
                    If Controls("Item" & i).Value <> vbNullString Then
                        .Range("A" & i + 6).Offset(0, 6).Value = Controls("OptionOut" & i).Value
                        Controls("OptionIn" & i).Enabled = True
                        Controls("OptionOut" & i).Enabled = True
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next ctl
      Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Why you are using "for i=2 to Number of Controls" and immediately use "for each ctl in controls list"? It seems it is enough to use one of them and generate the other manually.

Comment: @Hamed I am trying to concatenate the name of the controls with the i to get the right name of the controls for "GroupItems1". Not too experienced with user form so maybe it's not the best approach what i've done.

Comment: @Hamed Maybe you are right i can just manually increment i each time it goes through the loop and use that rather the looping over and over with i and ctl?

Comment: Just build a control array when you initialize the form and use that.

Comment: @Comintern Unfortunately that is a little bit complicated at the moment for what i know so far to do.

Comment: @QuickSilver It's only complicated if you're using dynamic controls or want shared event handling. I'm talking about simply declaring a module level array `Private TextBoxes() As MSForms.TextBox` or something like that, then manually adding them in `Initialize`.